# Playwright Python Unable to connect to remote browser instance

Tags: python, chromium, playwright, playwright-python

```
/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 377, in dispatch
    parsed_error = parse_error(error["error"])  # type: ignore
KeyError: 'error'
```

I am running docker image of browserless/chrome and trying to connect to it
but above error is what i get with the following python script:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
p = sync_playwright().start()
url = "https://www.google.com"
browser = p.chromium.connect(
        "ws://10.192.1.165:3000"
    )
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()
page.goto(url)
print(page.content())
```

Any help would be appreciated.

- I tried to check the websocket with other applications and it works and responds just as expected.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? Running your code on 3.10.12 with `playwright==1.37.0` on Ubuntu 22.04 gives me a `playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.` error on line 4, `browser = p.chromium.connect(`. Which is the expected result since the endpoint doesn't exist. Please share a [mcve] or whatever details may be necessary to reproduce the unexpected `KeyError`. Thanks.